# create/schedule a scheduler in webMethods to call a service with 2 (or more) input options

Tags: webmethods

How can I create/schedule a scheduler in webMethods to call a service with 2 (or more) input options?

Here, I need to invoke a service through options (inputs) which will route to another map service to TN, but I need to know about a scheduler with input options (more than 1 options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure the flow service that you are scheduling has two or more inputs defined. 
For example, consider scheduling the flow service `pub.math:addInts` which has 2 inputs.

In your scheduler menu, click the Assign Inputs option and give your inputs as in figure below and click on SAVE.[image: Multiple inputs in single schedule WebMethods]

Comment: Hi Nishanthi, Thank you for your answer.